# React App API Patch call getting 500 error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, rest-api

I've got a react application running in a lightning container. Queries to the rest API via a get request work just fine, but upserting data via the patch request just gets a 500 error with no message or error being shown.

The upsert approach works fine on my dev org, but once packaged and installed in the sandbox org it doesn't work.

Help

Comment: I've installed the same package into my dev org and it works just fine, so it only seems to be effecting the sandbox org.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we had to switch to a new URL after sandbox refresh (Salesforce is changing sandbox location after refresh and thus URL is different). But it was really wired that GET/POST requests worked and PATCH only didn't.

New URL can be obtained from `instance_url` field from `/oauth2/token` response.